# How to get session[""] value in java script?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flash

how to get value of session["new"] in java script function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        jwplayer("container").setup({  
            flashplayer:'jwplayer/player.swf',
            file:'Video/Baby.FLV',  //How to set session["new"] value as file value.
            height:470,  
            width:320  
        });  
        </script>
```

i have the song file-name in session["new"], got it from another page.

can anyone tell me how to set file name in java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using asp.net?
you should be able to do like file:<%=Session["new"]%>

Comment: I'm assuming he'll probably want to JSON encode that too... not sure what the proper syntax in 'vanilla' asp.net is, but with MVC3+Razor you'd do something like `var session = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["new"]));` i.e., to pass a C# variable into a JS variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read or write a **server-side** value (session-state) directly from the client-side. Setting a *cookie*, however, would work (since a cookie can be shared between client and server, and can be manipulated by the client-side code). You may find [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) useful.